# splitting a string to access integer within it

Tags: vb.net

i have a string `"<PinX F='53mm'></PinX>"`, I want to access the 53 within the string and do some addition to it and then add the answer back into that string. I've been thinking about this and wasn't sure whether this can be done with regular expression or not? Can anybody help me out.

thanks

Comment: Please consider marking one of the below answers as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a regular expression. This will get the digits, parse them to a number, add one to it, and put it back in the string (that is, the result is actually a new string as strings are immutable).

```
string s = Regex.Replace(
  input,
  @"(\d+)",
  m => (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) + 1).ToString()
);
```

Comment: sorry not really familiar with regex, but what does the m stand for here?

Comment: @StefanReaney: That's a lambda expression for a method to handle each match. The `m` is a parameter for a `MatchEvaluator` method, so it will be of the type `Match`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Why use the HAP for this simple string?

Comment: is there another way to do it?

Comment: @Oded, Using HAP will allow for change in the data structure. Regexes and substring solution rely on the data being a constant structure.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - I know the HAP and use it where needed. Looks like overkill here. There is nothing suggesting that the format will change. Additionally, even with the HAP the attribute value would need to be parsed again (as the HAP would return "53mm" and not a numeric value).

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression looks like a good fit for this particular problem:

```
\d+
```

Will match one or more digits.

```
Int32.Parse(Regex.Match("<PinX F='53mm'></PinX>", @"\d+").Value)
```

Will return 53.

Answer (score 0):

In this single case yes.  `"'(.*?)'` then access the first group, but if this is part of a larger xml regular expressions should not be used.  You should utilize the xml parser build into .net find the attribute with xsd and get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, here's a small routine...

```
' Set testing string
Dim s As String = "<PinX F='53mm'></PinX>"

' find first occurence of CHAR ( ' )
Dim a As Integer = s.IndexOf("'")
' find last occurence of CHAR ( ' )
Dim b As Integer = s.LastIndexOf("'")

' get substring "53mm" from string
Dim substring As String = s.Substring(a, b - a)

' get integer values from substring
Dim length As Integer = substring.Length
Dim c As Char = Nothing
Dim result As String = Nothing
For i = 1 To length - 1
    c = substring.Chars(i)
    If IsNumeric(c) Then
        result = result & c
    End If
Next

Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(result))
Console.ReadLine()
```